# What should i do if i have a componet with many methods that have a lot of code and logic in it and this logic is reused in many other components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, design-patterns, components

I am building an application with a lot of screens (components) each one has some methods such as save, add, delete, redo, view, and other functions. every function of them has a lot of code in it.

now I have declared these functions outside my components and call them from my methods attached to the screen component so I can access them. when I call them I pass this keyword as an argument so I can access the state and props from these functions.

I did this to be able to share this logic across the components.

now my question: Is this a best practice?
if yes what is the best way to do this
if not what should I do instead

note I am using react

Comment: *best practice* is a highly opinionated subject - *if yes what is the best way to do this* the way that makes sense to you and your fellow developers

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Custom Hook that contains all the re-used logic you have if that what's you want.

Read more about this feature here:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html
https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_customhooks.asp